# Characteristic function of multiplication of two independent r.v.s

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, characteristic-functions

$X$ is r.v. with Exponential with $\lambda=1$ and Y has a characteristic function $e^{-|t|^a}$ for $a\in (0,2)$. What is the characteristic function of $Z=X^{\frac{1}{a}}Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Here's what I have found out so far:

$$
\varphi_{X^{\frac{1}{a}}Y}(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{itX^{\frac{1}{a}}Y}) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(e^{itX^{\frac{1}{a}}Y}|X)) = \dots
$$

Now 
$$
\mathbb{E}(e^{itX^{\frac{1}{a}}Y}) = \mathbb{E}(e^{itx^{\frac{1}{a}}Y})|_{x=X} = \varphi_Y(tx^{\frac{1}{a}})|_{x=X} = e^{-|x^{\frac{1}{a}}t|^a}|_{x=X} = e^{-|t|^aX}
$$
so

$$
\dots = \mathbb{E}e^{-|t|^aX}
$$

Here I got stuck. I haven't been formally introduced to Laplace's transform and I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ has an exponential distribution of parameter one, it follows that 
$$
\mathbb E\left[f(X)\right]=\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-x}dx
$$
for each continuous bounded function $f$. Apply this for a fixed $t$ to $f(x)=\exp\left(-\lvert t\rvert^\alpha x\right)$; you will be reduced to compute an integral of the form $\int_0^\infty e^{-Ax}dx$ for some $A$.

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-|t|^a}e^{-x}dx = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x(1+|t|^a})dx = \frac{e^{-x(1+|t|^a)}}{1+|t|^a} |_0^{\infty} = \frac{1}{1+|t|^a}$. Is that the final answer?

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}$